# Using DLL on server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll

I have two network and both network have server. And one network have server with database that i need to access from the client which is belong to another network.

Now I have dll that have methods for connecting on database, so i mean to make webservice which going to include this dll as a reference and client application going to have this webservice as a web reference! But this is going to be belong difficult.

So can i just put dll on server and use it from client application?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're already installing an application on the client, why not install the DLL there as well? This doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you actually try this and if there are problems, then ask a more specific question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you'll have to modify the [code access security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) policy. This is usually much harder than just copying the file locally.